# How to calculate the throughput in Cooja simulator

Tags: contiki

---

Hi All,

I work with example/ipv6/rpl-udp files in cooja simulator. How do I measure the amount of throughput in the network?

With the command "powertrace_start(CLOCK_SECOND * 60); " in the client.c code, I get the Powertrace output.

Can I use this method?

throughput= packet received / Simulation time

Simulation time = (ENERGEST_TYPE_TRANSMIT + ENERGEST_TYPE_LISTEN) / 32768

Is the method correct?

Thanks in advance,

Nasrin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that is not correct as `ENERGEST_TYPE_*` are constants.

One way to do it is with [Cooja simulator scripts](https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/wiki/Using-Cooja-Test-Scripts-to-Automate-Simulations).

For example, let's say you have a C program that prints "Message transmitted" every time the node sends a message to another node and "Message received" every time it receives as message.

A Cooja script can automatically run the simulation for a specific time and count the messages. This code works for me:

```
TIMEOUT(100000); // simulation duration in milliseconds

num_messages_tx = 0;
num_messages_rx = 0;

timeout_function = function () {
    log.log("Script timed out.\n");
    log.log("Messages transmitted: " + num_messages_tx + " \n");
    log.log("Messages received:    " + num_messages_rx + " \n");
    log.testOK();
}

while (true) {
    if (msg) {
        if(msg.startsWith("Message transmitted")) {
            num_messages_tx += 1;
        }
        if(msg.startsWith("Message received")) {
            num_messages_rx += 1;
        }
    }

    YIELD();
}
```

To start using it, save the code (its JavaScript) in a file `test.js` and add this to your `.csc` Cooja configuration file:

```
<plugin>
  org.contikios.cooja.plugins.ScriptRunner
  <plugin_config>
    <scriptfile>[CONFIG_DIR]/test.js</scriptfile>
    <active>true</active>
  </plugin_config>
  <width>457</width>
  <z>4</z>
  <height>427</height>
 <location_x>3</location_x>
 <location_y>404</location_y>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Dear @kfx , Thanks for the answer. With this method, I will get the total number of packets received and sent.This amount should be divided on what Time?

Comment: For calculation "throughput" in the network. (The packet size is 59 bytes and simulation time= 30 min)

Comment: One option is to use the simulation duration for the time. In the example `TIMEOUT(100000)` sets the total duration of the simulation.

Comment: In this case, the throughput value will be very low. Can I use the total "all-transmit/32768" and "all-listen/32768" times in powertarce.c?

Comment: Dear @kfx, Thanks for the answer. In this case, the throughput value will be very low. Can I use the total "all-transmit/32768" and "all-listen/32768" times in powertarce.c?

Comment: No, as `all_listen` is simply the time spent in listening, even if nothing is received. To get higher throughput, send more packets...

Comment: This method does not give any results.

Comment: @kfx I cannot change the .csc file because i run contiki OS in guest mode.

Comment: I get this result:Script timed out.
Messages transmitted: 0 
Messages received:    0 
TEST OK
[if test was run without visualization, Cooja would now have been terminated]

Comment: @Tasneem I'm confused what you are saying there. Did you test the code or not?